# iTunes opens Photos

Tags: itunes, photos, macos

When I open iTunes on OS X 10.11 it also opens Photos! 
It doesn't close it when I exit.

I hardly ever use Photos, so how can I stop this annoying behaviour.

Comment: How long has this been happening? Have you changed anything recently that would be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Next time Photos opens when you plug in your device there should be a little check box next to the device name in the upper left hand corner that says "Open Photos when this device is connected." Uncheck that and you should be good to go.